# Swift - update object in place

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, oop

If I want to update existing class object is there any easier way than duplicating init to update method? (my Person object has about ten properties which are defined firstly or can be edited at later app usage)

problems listed in example below:

1. person1 reinitialization does not update reference to a person1 object in a parent-child array - child array does not contain updated object
2. person2 object behaves as wanted (child array contains updated object) but uses duplicated initializer code in update method to make “edit in place” which looks really bad in terms of DRY

any hints how to do it Swiftly?

```
import UIKit

class Person {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var age: Int?

    init(name: String, surname: String, age: Int? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
    }

    func update(name: String, surname: String, age: Int? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
    }
}
class Parent {
    var child = [Person]()
}

var parent = Parent()

var person1 = Person(name: "John", surname: "Doe")
print(person1.name)
parent.child.append(person1)
person1 = Person(name: "Jack", surname: "Doe")
print(person1.name)

print(parent.child.first!.name)

var person2 = Person(name: "Tom", surname: "Cruise")
print(person2.name)
parent.child.append(person2)
person2.update(name: "Jim", surname: "Cruise")
print(person2.name)

print(parent.child.last!.name)
```

to make it more clear think about the array of user profiles where you can add a new profile or edit an existing one. and above problem is about editing existing user profile

Comment: Why not simply omit `update()` and update single properties manually like `person2.name = "Jim"`?

Comment: for 2 as in example that's ok but my object have it about 10, so when I update it in VC this adds huge amount of lines. So I thought there is some easier way to do it?

Comment: Eventually you need **one** line of code to update **one** property. So you have a *huge amount of lines* either in the VC or in the class. And there is no benefit of an update method with 10 parameters. If you want to update only two you have to check which parameters are going to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation for both of your queries,

**1.** `parent child array` contains the `reference` to the `person1` object, i.e. `person1 and parent child array` store the reference to same object.

```
var person1 = Person(name: "John", surname: "Doe")
parent.child.append(person1)
```

Now, you're assigning a `new object to person1` instead of making changes to the same object, i.e.

```
person1 = Person(name: "Jack", surname: "Doe")
```

This won't reflect in the `parent child array`. It will still contain the reference to the previous `Person` object.

This is the reason you are getting different values of name in person1 and `parent child array`

```
print(person1.name) //Jack
print(parent.child.first!.name) //John
```

**2.** Instead of adding a separate method for updating the object - `update(name:surname:age:)`, you can simply update the values individually using the `. operator` on object's properties, i.e

```
var person2 = Person(name: "Tom", surname: "Cruise")
parent.child.append(person2)

person2.name = "Jim"
```

Since in the above code, instead of assigning a new `Person` object to `person2`, we're just updating its values.

So, `person2` and `parent child array's object` will still `reference the same object` and hence will print the same `name` values.

```
print(person2.name) //Tom
print(parent.child.last!.name) //Tom
```

Comment: When few years ago I was programming in php and symfony framework there were setters and getters for every property and properties were private. With this approach it looks almost all other way. But if this is the proper Swifty way I will accept your guided answer.

Comment: That approach was Objective-C thing. Swift is much more easy and straightforward.